# how to adjust submenu inside Mat-mdc-menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Does anyone know how to adjust the padding of a submenu of a mat-menu inside a mat-menu for Angular Material 15 and upwards?

Custom class didn't work, nor the .mat-mdc-content.mat-mdc-content selector in the css file for the component. Inline styling also does nothing.